# EndGetResponse exception

Tags: c#, exception, httpwebrequest, protocols

I'm using `GetResponseAsync` for a GET request. The exception thrown is

> WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure
>   channel at EndGetResponse.

I've checked several other questions regarding this, tried applying this:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                        | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                        | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                        | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

In order to bypass this issue, but I'm going nowhere with that. The weird part is that some connections go through without *any* exceptions, but occasionally this exception is thrown.

I've tried implementing a retry loop, which works fine, but I just feel it's a dirty workaround, especially because it can throw the exception several times in a row and it slows the process down. Something I don't want because it's very performance bound and I need the code to work as fast as possible.

What would the cause of this exception be?

Edit: The same piece of code was working fine several days ago without having any trouble with protocols. The problem came up after I reinstalled and switched to Windows 10 (if it has anything to do with it). The requests were made to the exact same server before that, so the problem must be on my end.

Comment: could this simply be a network issue? latency? or maybe remote end point is blocking connections at some stage and then resetting back the access? or a hardware issue?

Comment: @marto I've ran the same code on the same PC several days ago, for a lot of time without having any of this. But recently I reinstalled and switched to Windows 10, ever since I've been getting this exception. I've tried playing around, trying to figure out what the cause might be. Actually a lot of digging, but nothing came up. Edit: Forgot to mention the requests were done to the same server, so the problem should be on my end.

Comment: other thoughts that come to mind is another type of anti-virus fitering, firewall issues, after switching to the new os perhaps you could try to ping the endpoint: ping ip -n 2000 to see if packets are loss or could scan your secure ports with a loop or something to see if there is a pattern when you get cut off, or/and checking the server configuration if you must register your new configuration somewhere (ip exception or something) I image your case like google sometimes asks if user is a robot, but probably if you have a certain flag it will never ask you...

Comment: @marto I am going to run some tests on the ports and pinging and report back. As for the configuration, the server I am connecting accepts public requests. It's a public REST API / get requests that anyone could use without specifying your configuration. The responses are JSon, but that's not something that matters.

Comment: @marto Out of 600 pings, only 2 were lost because of a timeout. Ports don't seem to have any problem.

Comment: since you are using async requests maybe you are violating some windows concurrent outbound connection limits? does the problem occure when you run only one *not-async* request?